# Adding nulls to dataframe output with regexp replace in Spark 2.4

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I am trying to use regex replace to add a string "null" to the output. Language is Spark Scala 2.40 in aws glue. What is the best approach for this problem?

I am creating a dataframe by dataframe select and parsing through the columns that I need to add "null" to:

```
 var select_df = raw_df.select(
          col("example_column_1"),
          col("example_column_2"),
          col("example_column_3")
      )
```

Input of example_column_1

```
#;#;Runner#;#;bob
```

Desired Output of example_column_1

```
null#;null#;Runner#;null#;bob
```

Attempt:

```
select_df.withColumn("example_column_1", regexp_replace(col("example_column_1"), "", "null"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The task can be split into two parts:

1. replace `#` at the beginning of the string
2. replace all occurences of `;#`

```scala
select_df
  .withColumn("example_column_1", regexp_replace('example_column_1, "^#", "null#"))
  .withColumn("example_column_1", regexp_replace('example_column_1, ";#", ";null#"))
  .show(false)
```