# Applying transformation to column in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

What is the best way to apply the following transformation to a column in a dataframe in Spark 2.40 Scala. I was attempting udf or regex replace but could not achieve the desired outcome.

column_1 in the below example is a string.

Data frame Input:

```
column_1
#;#;Runner#;#;bob
#;#;#;
```

Desired Result

```
column_1
null#;null#;Runner#;null#;bob
null#;null#;null
```

Solution:

Following the suggestions below. This was how I resolved the issue. In this case I replaced with commas first then later replaced the comma delimiter with #;

```
select_df
  .withColumn("column_1", regexp_replace(col("column_1"), "(?<![a-zAZ0-9]),", "null,"))
  .withColumn("column_1", regexp_replace(col("column_1"), ",]$", ",null"))
  .withColumn("column_1", regexp_replace(col("column_1"), ",", "#;"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding nulls to dataframe output with regexp replace in Spark 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68656179/adding-nulls-to-dataframe-output-with-regexp-replace-in-spark-2-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp_replace 2 times to get required output. First, replace #; (only the #; which are not preceeded by Runner using [negative look behind regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)) by null#;  and then replace ending #; with empty string.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val df = List("#;#;Runner#;#;bob", "#;#;#;").toDF(("column_1"))

  df.withColumn("column_1", regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace('column_1, "(?<![a-zA-Z]+)#;", "null#;"),"#;$", "")
  )
    .show(false)
+-----------------------------+
|column_1                     |
+-----------------------------+
|null#;null#;Runner#;null#;bob|
|null#;null#;null             |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: What if the value is dynamic? Runner may not always be present, in the same position. It could be "llama" in a different position as an example

Comment: You can change regex pattern like this -(?<![a-zA-Z]+)#;